# Set ports on a Docker compose file for Amazon ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I am following [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploy-applications-on-amazon-ecs-using-docker-compose/) to deploy my app to AWS using docker compose.

If I use `docker compose up` I get this error:

`published port can't be set to a distinct value than container port: incompatible attribute`

This is the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
    www:
        image: my_image_path:latest
        ports:
            - "8001:80"
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www/html/
        links:
            - db
        networks:
            - default
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.8
        links:
            - db:db
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
```

I have two services listening to port 80 in the container, so I cannot just use `80:80` in both of them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change one of your docker images to listen on another port. Docker-compose deploys to AWS Fargate, and there are some restrictions in Fargate that are preventing your configuration from working:

1. Multiple containers in a single Fargate task  have to listen on distinct ports.
2. The published port can't be different from the port the container is listening on. If you needed to change the port clients connect to, that can be done in the ALB/Target Group settings, instead of the container settings.

Since one of your images is [phpmyadmin](https://hub.docker.com/_/phpmyadmin?tab=description) I suggest simply adding an environment variable to that image `APACHE_PORT: 8000` which will change the port the Apache web server in that container listens on to port `8000`. Then you can set the port mapping on that container to `8000:8000` and set the port mapping on your `www` container to `80:80`